# Oracle 10G installation on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle

i have faced some problems when i install oracle 10g on Linux OS anyone can send me the exact tutorial or link of oracle installation on Linux.
                                                 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which Oracle product or Linux distribution you are using, but there are tutorials for many distributions on the Oracle site here:

- [Oracle-on-Linux Installation Guides](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/linux/install/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

SLES makes it really easy.

[Install Oracle on SLES11](http://www.novell.com/products/server/oracle/documents.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think [www.oracle-base.com](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/ArticlesLinux.php)
is the best resource for oracle installations on linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better answer these days!

Download Virtual Box 4.0 ( https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads )

and then Download a Developer VM to put into your Virtual Box ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html )

Using these two techniques will isolate the side effects of trying to install/ configure a database.